# Bucketing in R or SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, oracle, bucket-sort

I am completely stumped on a problem and would like some guidance.  I am picking random sets of 8 numbers from the set of 1 to 8 (for example, 5,6,8,1,3,4,2,7) and trying to bucket those numbers as subsets of sequential numbers according to the order they appear.

For the example above, the first bucket would start with a 5 then the 6 would be added.  Upon hitting the 8 a new bucket would be started. Whenever we get to a number that belongs in an existing bucket (e.g., when we reach `2`, it can be added to `1`'s bucket), we add it there. In this example, after all 8 numbers we'd arrive at:

```
5,6,7
8
1,2
3,4
```

For a total of 4 buckets.

I am not actually concerned with the contents of the buckets, I just want to count how many buckets there are for a given random set of 8 digits.  I plan on looping through a set of 1000 of these 8 digit sequences.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this. 7 didn't appear in the first sequence. Neither 2 in the third.

Comment: So the idea is that we are going through digit by digit, creating a new bucket if a number isn't in sequence when any previous bucket.  So 5 creates the first, 6 goes in it.  8 Creates the second bucket.  1 creates the third.  3 creates the 4th.  Then 4,2 and 7 are appended to already existing buckets (because they are in sequence).  Odd problem, yes, but kind of an interesting one.

Comment: So sort of like creating Solitaire stacks...

Answer (score 5):

If you are just interested in the number of buckets,

```
## Your data
dat <- c( 5,6,8,1,3,4,2,7)

## Get the number of buckets
count <- 0
for (i in seq_along(dat))
    if (!((dat[i] - 1) %in% dat[1:i])) count <- count+1
count
# 4
```

and, more succinctly in a function

```
countBuckets <- function(lst) sum(sapply(1:length(lst), function(i)
    (!((lst[i]-1) %in% lst[1:i]))))
```

And, here is a recursive implementation to get the contents of buckets.

```
f <- function(lst, acc=NULL) {
    if (length(lst) == 0) return(acc)
    if (missing(acc)) return( Recall(lst[-1], list(lst[1])) )

    diffs <- sapply(acc, function(x) lst[1] - x[length(x)] == 1)
    if (any(diffs)) {
        acc[[which(diffs)]] <- c(acc[[which(diffs)]], lst[1])
    } else { acc <- c(acc, lst[1]) }
    return ( Recall(lst[-1], acc) )
}

f(dat)

# [[1]]
# [1] 5 6 7
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 3 4
```

Comment: This answer is not getting its well deserved appreciation

Answer (score 5):

My solution, not ripped of from nongkrong but quite similar. You get the count of buckets:

```
x <- as.integer(c(5,6,8,1,3,4,2,7))
sum(is.na(sapply(1:length(x), function(i) which((x[i]-1L)==x[1:i])[1L])))
# [1] 4
```

I believe it is possible to vectorize it, then it would scale perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @jangorecki but quicker:

```
x <- sample(8L)
1 + sum(sapply(2L:8L, function(i) !any(x[i] - x[1:(i - 1L)] == 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized answer:

```
ind.mat <- matrix(rep(1:8, each=8), ncol=8)
ind.mat[upper.tri(ind.mat)] <- NA
8 - sum(rowSums(matrix(rep(x, 8), ncol=8) - x[ind.mat] == 1, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Note that we only need to declare `ind.mat` once, so scales up well to replication.

Comment: Also it should get a much bigger speed up if OP can provide all 1000 cases and build a single matrix on them. In the most pessimistic implementation the case id would form an additional dimension in the array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with R, but you can definitely do something like:

```
setOf8 = your array of 8 numbers
buckets=0
for( i = [2,8] )
{
    if( (setOf8[i] < setOf8[i-1]) )
    {
        buckets = buckets + 1
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You could do something like:

```
func countBuckets( buckets, set )
{
    set = your array
    current = 1
    for( i = [2,size(set)] )
    {
        if( set[current] + 1 == set[i] )
        {
            set.remove( current )
            current = set[i-1]
        }
    }
    if( size(set) == 0 )
    {
        return buckets
    }
return countBuckets( buckets + 1, set )
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've started with something like that, but the problem happens with numbers like that last 7, it's not in sequence, but it doesn't start a new bucket.  It needs to get appended to the first bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it will fare on Oracle, but since you have added the SQL Server tag, here is a T-SQL solution:

```
declare @set char(8) = '56813427';

with cte as (
    select s.Id, cast(substring(@set, s.Id, 1) as int) as [Item]
    from dbo.Sequencer s
    where s.Id between 1 and 8
    union all
    select 9 as [Id], 0 as [Item]
)
select count(*) as [TotalBuckets]
from cte s
    inner join cte n on (s.Item = n.Item - 1) and s.Id > n.Id;
```

The idea behind it is to count the cases when next number goes before the current one, beginning a new bucket rather than continuing the current one. The only problem here is with boundaries, so I added trailing zero. Without it, least set item (1 in your case) is not counted as a separate bucket.

P.S. `dbo.Sequencer` is a table with incrementing integers. I usually keep one in the database to project ordered sequences.